# Android GMaps v2 handle orientation change

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have troubles with handling orientation change using google maps fragment.
The problem is when I use these lines to prevent Map reload when orientation changed, i do not have my land-layout loaded and when I change orientation back it throws

> Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment

This is manifest code, which I found to prevent map reload. If I will ignore these lines my app will handle orientation change but map will be reloaded every time I change orientation.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenSize|fontScale"
 android:screenOrientation="user"
```

This is my Fragment

```
    public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_screen_map, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        populateViewForOrientation(inflater, (ViewGroup) getView());
    }

    private void populateViewForOrientation(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        View subview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_screen_map, viewGroup);

    }
}
```

This is my Activity

```
    public class MainScreenMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainshit);
      BlankFragment frag= new BlankFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, frag)
                .addToBackStack("myStack")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

My port-layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#33ffffff"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#33ffffff"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

My land-layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33ffffff"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33ffffff"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: AFAIK, android saves your dynamically added fragment and it's state when you rotate your device. So you check the fragment previously added or not using fragment manager in onCreate method of Activity.